# Retrofit 2 Sequential Posts

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am just now learning about Retrofit 2.  In my app Intent "UploadToServer"
I have three async tasks that I need to call sequentially:
1. Post UserName and get back UserId.
2. Post Geolocation and some other string data and get back a "report ticket number".
3. Post a jpg image along with the ticket number.
I have a web service running on my server.

In standard hand-coded Java I would use a looper or something equivalent.
How could this be accomplished using Retrofit 2?  And oh, I would like to have a progress bar moving, especially when uploading the jpg image file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the calls using the callbacks:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_WEBAPI)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();

    mService = retrofit.create(IWebApi.class);
    ...
    mService.first_operation(...params...).enqueue(callback);
```

callback is an instance of a class that expects the results of first_operation. If first_operation success, then call the second_method.

```
    public class Example implements Callback<void> {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(Response<LoginResponse> response) {
          second_method();
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {        
           t.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

I use a ProgressDialog with indeterminated in true. You can show it right before the call to the service and hide when a response arrives, in the onResponse or in the onFailure methods.

```
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, getString(R.string.wait_plaease),
            getString(R.string.executing_action), true);
```